# Is it bad to make network calls and handle responses in an adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter

I have been tasked with remaking an entire app basically at work. Essentially the app is just a feed that contains multiple types of cards (think facebook with update cards, photo cards, OG content cards) etc. I moved all of the network handling into a single class. You call the method that contains the request you want, passing in relative parameters and a Listener. The network call is made and then the Listener is passed the response.

Currently I have a Fragment class that populates a recyclerview with my custom adapter. The Fragment class interacts with my network class by making pagination requests on an endpoint. Should I have an adapter listener that communicates with my fragment when for example, the like icon on a particular viewHolder card is clicked? Should I then have the fragment make and manage that network call? The issue I have to account for here is if a network response fails, I need to unset UI elements (like the color of a like icon) to notify the user that their request could not be completed at this time. Unsetting these elements are properties of the view holder at that position in the recycler view. It seems wrong to pass all of this view holder information back to the fragment just to have the fragment be the only class that interacts with my network class. Is there anything inherently wrong with having my adapter handle network requests as well.

For example, Set an onClickListener on my view holder element, when clicked update the UI and make the call, then respond back to the adapter. If successful leave everything be, if failure, then unset the UI. This pattern makes sense to me and decouples individual view logic from the fragment. Is this fine to do? A lot of google searching has lead me to believe otherwise. This is my first business application and I want to make sure I follow the best patterns possible.

My fragment for the record looks something like this

```
onCreate() {
  networkListener = new NetworkResponseListener() {
    //Process success response based on response code
    onSuccess(JSONObject response, responseCode) 
    onError(Error e, responseCode) // Handle Errors
  }
}

//After scroll listener indicates I need to fetch again
NetworkHelper.makeFeedFetch(networkListener, LastId, GET_FEED_REQUEST_CODE);
```

So essentially I would do the same type of Network interaction in my adapter class for actions like, viewHolder like icon clicked and so on. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make sure you follow the best patterns, you shouldn't make NetworkCalls from your fragment. Fragments or Activities should be just viewed objects that show the data that is served to them by other classes like Presenters(if you follow MVP) or ViewModels(MVVM). These classes also do not make direct network calls.

Generally, we use the Repository pattern which gets data from the remote(web services, remote DBs etc.) or local sources(a local DB).
Your network class is a candidate for a repository source. Then for each action
that is necessary for our business logic, we generate a use case, and if this use case needs the repository we inject our repository to our use case. Then we inject this use case to our Presenter or ViewModel. This much of indirection may seem like overkill but it gives easily extensible and testable code. Recycler view is also a view so you shouldn't make network calls
inside of recycler view too.

Although not an exact solution, your

> Set an onClickListener on my view holder element, when clicked update the UI and make the call, then respond back to the adapter

is better IMO.